# how to extract data from <li> that is in <ul> class"list-unstyled search-vehicle-info-2 fs13"

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

How do I get data from li which in Ul class and place it under appropriate headers.
[image]

```
car_data = soup.find_all("li")
data =[]
for name in car_data:
    data.append({"Car data": name.text})

df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all info from the `<ul>` tag into a pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/660cc-cars/190519"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for ul in soup.select("ul.search-vehicle-info-2"):
    car_name = ul.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
    info = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in ul.select("li")]
    all_data.append([car_name, *info])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["Car Name", "Year", "KM", "Type", "CC", "Type 2"]
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                             Car Name  Year          KM    Type      CC     Type 2
0       Suzuki Wagon R  2017 Hybrid FZ 660cc for Sale  2017   17,000 km  Hybrid  660 cc  Automatic
1                Daihatsu Move  2017 L 660cc for Sale  2017   10,450 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
2                Suzuki Every  2016 PA 660cc for Sale  2016   35,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
3              Suzuki Alto  2014 ECO-S 660cc for Sale  2014   90,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
4                 Mazda Carol  2014 XS 660cc for Sale  2014   63,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
5                Suzuki Every  2017 PA 660cc for Sale  2017  129,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
6                  Nissan Dayz  2018 X 660cc for Sale  2018   45,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
7                Daihatsu Esse  2010 X 660cc for Sale  2010   85,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
8               Nissan Clipper  2016 E 660cc for Sale  2016   75,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
9                Suzuki Alto  2019 VXL 660cc for Sale  2019   38,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
10               Daihatsu Mira  2018 X 660cc for Sale  2018   22,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
11      Honda N One  2015 G L Package  660cc for Sale  2015   72,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
12        Suzuki Cervo  2007 G Limited 660cc for Sale  2007   84,500 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
13              Sogo Family Van  2019  660cc for Sale  2019   67,000 km     CNG  700 cc     Manual
14                Suzuki Alto  2016 VP 660cc for Sale  2016   66,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
15                 Suzuki Every  2014  660cc for Sale  2014  111,111 km  Petrol  660 cc     Manual
16                 Mitsubishi I  2007  660cc for Sale  2007  105,780 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
17     Suzuki Wagon R  2014 Stingray X 660cc for Sale  2014   81,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
18               Suzuki Alto  2020 VXR 660cc for Sale  2020    8,000 km  Petrol  660 cc     Manual
19                 Honda N One  2015 G 660cc for Sale  2015   72,000 km  Petrol  660 cc     Manual
20               Suzuki Alto  2019 VXL 660cc for Sale  2019   25,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
21           Toyota Pixis Epoch  2016  660cc for Sale  2016  170,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
22        Daihatsu Move  2012 Custom G 660cc for Sale  2012  167,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
23      Suzuki Wagon R  2018 Hybrid FZ 660cc for Sale  2018   97,500 km  Hybrid  660 cc  Automatic
24                  Suzuki Alto  2013  660cc for Sale  2013   71,850 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
25  Daihatsu Move Conte  2016 CUSTOM G 660cc for Sale  2016   48,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
26             Suzuki Alto  2013 ECO-L 660cc for Sale  2013   50,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
27        Daihatsu Mira  2013 Custom L 660cc for Sale  2013  170,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
28               Suzuki Alto  2020 VXL 660cc for Sale  2020   20,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
29               Subaru Sambar   2019  660cc for Sale  2019  120,000 km  Petrol  660 cc     Manual
30               Suzuki Alto  2021 VXR 660cc for Sale  2021    3,000 km  Petrol  660 cc     Manual
31              Mazda Carol Eco  2013  660cc for Sale  2013   82,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
32                Daihatsu Mira  2017  660cc for Sale  2017  135,950 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
33            Daihatsu Mira  2013 L SA 660cc for Sale  2013  115,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
34             Suzuki MR Wagon  2009 G 660cc for Sale  2009  150,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
35  Suzuki Wagon R  2008 Stingray J Style 660cc fo...  2008   48,000 km  Petrol  660 cc  Automatic
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]